# Angular $http request not returning Rails resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, angularjs

I'd like to get a JSON object of all the posts in my database.

Here's the module:

```
angular
.module('AngularRails', [
    'ngRoute',
    'templates'
    ]).config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          });
    });
```

A controller:

```
angular.module('AngularRails')
  .controller('PostsController', function($scope, $http) {
    var posts = $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
      return data;
    });

    $scope.posts = posts;
  });
```

The view:

```
<h1>The Home View!</h1>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='post in posts'>
    {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I check the console, I can see that the request is made to the specified URL (and can see the JSON I want), but it's buried deeply within some large object.

How can I display the posts in an unordered list?

**Edit**

As per Dan's suggestion, I've changed the controller to this:

```
angular.module('AngularRails')
  .controller('PostsController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });
  });
```

No cigar.

Comment: Could you please post the response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are looking for will be passed as a parameter to the success callback from `$http`. `$scope.posts` in your example is the entire http object. Try something like this:

```
angular.module('AngularRails').controller('PostsController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(postData, status, headers, config){
        $scope.posts = postData; // this is the JSON from the web request
    });

    // $scope.posts = posts; <-- this was the $http promise object
});
```

**Example**

Rails controller:

```
def list
  posts = { posts: %w(post1 post2 post3 post4) } # Or ActiveRecord query etc...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: posts }
  end
end
```

Angualr controller:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/list.json').success (data) ->
    $scope.posts = data.posts
    console.log $scope.posts // ["post1", "post2", "post3", "post4"]
```

Comment: Hey, Dan! Thanks for your suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work. I updated the original post with what I tried. I did attempt to use the rest of the parameters, but I'm pretty sure it can be shortened to one (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @DylanRichards I've updated the answer with a better example, it would probably be useful to see what you are doing on the rails side but this should help. Also you are correct, the extra parameters in the success callback are not needed - that was just for illustration. Let me know if helps! (the js here is coffeescript!)